# What is the best shield for an anarchy spec Mechromancer?

Tags: borderlands-2

So I started playing this game again recently having picked up some of the DLCs and I'm currently doing an anarchy mechromancer.  From doing some reading it looks like the best gun to use is a redundant fibber, but what is the best shield for the build?

Comment: Probably Hide of terra but I didn't play Gaige much.

Comment: @AdrienXL I've come across that, but mostly for deathtrap builds.

Answer (score 1):

I'd basically recommend 2 shields.

first would be the bee if you wanna go pure dps since her skills restore shields on kills and it wouldnt have much downtime as a result. so you get quite the damage buff. However this comes at the cost of shields that would give you more survivability.

The alternative would be the sham. Absorbing bullets will give you more survivability (can go up to 94% absorb rate). Especially useful if using norfleet rocket (try to get a logans gun which is dropped from willhelm if you want to use rockets. while equipped with the sham, you can just shoot the ground with logans gun and absorb socket ammo from the splash explosions)